# Array is Empty Even After Declaring

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am attempting to store an Object into a variable after parsing a csv file. But the array is coming back empty after assigning it to the variable.

```
 var keywordsArray = []
    
CSVToJSON().fromFile('./csv/Campaign.csv')
    .then(campaigns => {
        // users is a JSON array
        // log the JSON array
         keywordsArray = campaigns
        
    }).catch(err => {
        // log error if any
        console.log(err);
    });

    console.log(keywordsArray);
```

Comment: You're working with an **asynchronous** API.

Comment: You are doing an `aysnc` op and in essence trying to log the variable when it hasn't been filled yet. console it inside `.then` to understand this.

Comment: You pressed the Pay button on a pizza ordering site, and are surprised your plate is still empty?

Comment: Aside from the snarky responses, how can I solve the problem I was asking?

Comment: I already was logging it inside of then. How do I actually put the results inside of the array so i can manipulate it outside of the async API?